# Coding Equation in Google Colab Python

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am starting a pre-course for python coding. I am brand new to coding and I am stuck on how to code this equation:

We need to calculate Joey's body mass index. Here's the formula for BMI:

> Weight(kg)/Height(m)^2 = BMI

This is what I tried:

```
78/1.82 ** 2=x
```

and this is the response I got:

> File "", line 1
>   78/1.82 ** 2=x
>               ^
>      SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Comment: You have your assignment the wrong way round. Should be `x = 78/1.82 ** 2`

Answer (score 0):

The way assignment operator " = " works is - it calculates the RHS to derive a value, and then assign it to the LHS variable. So it should be x = 78/(1.82 **2) [Brackets to cover arithmetic operator precedence, which might not be necessary for this case in particular]